# How can I control how many JUnit5 Test Instances are going to be generated in Runtime and apply separate ParameterResolver to each of the instance

Tags: junit5, junit5-extension-model

I'd like to execute Selenium Grid tests using Maven like this:

**mvn verify-Dtest=BaseTest** **-Dprop.selenium.server.url=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub**
**-Dprop.browser=chrome**
**-Dprop.version=80.0.3987.106**

I inject ChromeDriver into Test constructor using JUnit5 ParameterResolver interface

```java
   @ExtendWith(ChromeRemoteWebDriverParameterResolver.class)
   @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
   public class MultiBrowserDemoTest {

    RemoteWebDriver driver;

    public MultiBrowserDemoTest(RemoteDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver.getDriver();
    }


    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    public void testGrid() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        search.sendKeys("JUnit5 extensions");
        search.submit();
    }

    @AfterAll()
    void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

It works fine. But I can't see how to implement multi-browser test execution.

Let's say, I want to add multiple browsers -Dprop.browser=chrome, firefox, opera, ie11

I created multiple classes implementing ParameterResolver Interface. But JUnit5 does not let me inject them all into my Test Class. It does not create new instances of Test class either.

I tried to use TestInstanceFactory to create new Instances of my Test class and apply separate implementation of ParameterResolver interface, but it did not work for me.

**End Result:** I can run the same test in multiple browsers in parallel using Selenium Grid and only one Test Class that I will be able to instantiate multiple times with separate webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your scenario correctly, what you are asking for is support for what we call "parameterized containers" (i.e., something analogous to `@ParameterizedTest` but at the class level), which does not exist yet in JUnit Jupiter.

See JUnit Jupiter issues [#871](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/871) and [#878](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/878) for details.